# Keyboard not showing in webview android

Tags: java, android, webview, keyboard

I'm going nuts with this issue I have, showing the keyboard on a webview. 
I have done every single thing stackoverflow says, and still no success. Here's my code:

```
public void openChat(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Chat VM Latino");


        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://190.171.0.181:3001/");
        wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        alert.setView(wv);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cerrar",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
    }
```

And here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vmlatino"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.UI.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.UI.EscogerStreamActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.UI.RadioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.UI.RadioChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.UI.VideoViewDemo"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified"
            android:label="Media/VideoView"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.UI.VMChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm using the vitamio plugin for video streaming, any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you're using a dialog to show the WebView. Use an Activity instead. Dialogs have limited user interaction.

Comment: Hello! Thanks For the response. The thing is that if I leave the activity, the video streaming won't continue playing, and the idea is to chat while at least listening to the stream

Comment: Hmm. You could try putting the stream in an `Overlay` or dialog (stream is inside WebView right?) And try rebuilding the chat part in Android XML (assuming chat is also in Webview?). By having chat written in native Java you should be able to open the keyboard in a dialog or activity.

Comment: The stream is in vitamio, and the chat yes, within a webview.

Comment: Can you modify the code inside the chat webpage? You should use Android's Javascript method call API to open the keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't... I'll try doing that, the JavaScript thing, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I didn't use a `Dialog`, I added a float like `WebView`, and the keyboard was now showing.